# Collision detection doesn't take the height of the rectangle into consideration wpf canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I am trying to create collision detection for a rectangle that has height. Below is how I draw the rectangle on a canvas.

```
public void DrawVerticalWalls()
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { heightMultiplier.Add(rnd.Next(3, 15)); }
        var verticalYValues = heightPoints.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(3).ToList();
        verticalWall = new Rectangle()
        {
            Width = SnakeSquareSize,
            Height = SnakeSquareSize * heightMultiplier[0],
            Fill = wallBrush
        };
        GamePanel.Children.Add(verticalWall);
        Canvas.SetTop(verticalWall, verticalYValues[0]);
        Canvas.SetLeft(verticalWall, widthPoints[0]);
}
```

So I start by generating a random height multiplier and store each one in a list to use for all the rectangles. And then I also generate random numbers from a pre-written list for all the possible y-values for the rectangle.
And then I draw the rectangle using these randomly generated numbers and add it to the canvas.

Here is how I do the collision detection

```
if ((snakeHead.Position.X == Canvas.GetLeft(verticalWall)) && (snakeHead.Position.Y == Canvas.GetTop(verticalWall)))
{
      EndGame();
}
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't take the height of the rectangle into consideration and instead, the collision only happens at the tip of the rectangle which is the initial x and y coordinates of the rectangle. So how can I make it also include the randomised height in the collision?

Comment: Please, do not post code as images

Comment: I apologise, I am new to this, and I have edited my questions accordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for this by using a **for loop that adds 20x20 squares instead of a long rectangle**. And then saving the x and y coordinates of each of the squares in a list.

**For example, if the height multiplier is 15, I would add 15 squares on top of each other (Each square with a fixed and equal height) instead of adding a single square and then stretching it by giving it a height of 15.**

Here is the class that is used to store the positions of the squares

```
public class StoreWalls
{ 
    public Point position { get; set; }
}
```

And then I just made a list using this class

```
private List<StoreWalls> listWalls = new List<StoreWalls>();
```

And then I made the for loop that repeats depending on the int generated by the height multiplier which is shown before the loop.

```
int heightMultiplier = rnd.Next(3, 40);
for (int i = 0; i < heightMultiplier; i++)
{
    Wall = new Rectangle() { Width = SnakeSquareSize, Height = SnakeSquareSize, Fill = wallBrush };
    GamePanel.Children.Add(Wall);
    Canvas.SetTop(Wall, YValues[0]);
    Canvas.SetLeft(Wall, XValues[0]);
    listWalls.Add(new StoreWalls()
    {
        position = new Point(XValues[0], YValues[0])
    });
    YValues[0] = YValues[0] + SnakeSquareSize;
}
```

And finally, I did the collision by using a foreach that gets the positions of each wall, and compares it with the position of the head of the snake using an if statement.

```
foreach (StoreWalls wall in listWalls.Take(listWalls.Count))
{
    if ((wall.position.X == snakeHead.Position.X) && (wall.position.Y == snakeHead.Position.Y))
    {
        EndGame();
    }
}
```